# Any way to make C++ become duck typing

Tags: c++, ruby, qt

The superior asks me to change a whole Ruby TK GUI program to QML&C++. Not allow writing business logic and animation in QML. They want to use QML only for displaying `Image`, and control these Images on the C++ side, even Animation. 
The biggest problem is the Ruby program which I got, only mass and complex code, without any single comment and document about the code.

So I am trying to simply write the Ruby in C++ way. But ruby is the duck typing, is there any way make C++ become duck typing? Like `auto` member variable.

Or shall I give up and resign?

Comment: `void*` is the root of all evil.

Comment: dont confuse the auto keyword with weak typing - it's there to save typing the type when it can be deduced by the compiler

Comment: A better question here would be how to port a small piece of code from Ruby to C++, and that would require you to show what you have tried before asking.

Comment: Even if Ruby uses weak typing, how often does your program use that feature and change the type of a variable all the time!? If you think about other weakly typed languages that might be rarely the case if the program is designed properly (if you ignore simple numbers saved in strings or strings used as numbers or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn off the type safety rules of C++, but you can try to simulate some idioms available to weakly typed languages with type erasure technique, which can be implemented using `void*` such as `std::any` (which is to be introduced in the upcoming C++17 standard).

Another alternative is a tagged union such as `std::variant` (also in C++17) or `QVariant` since you use Qt, as pointed out by Mike. A tagged union has the requirement of having to know a list of potential types that the variable may hold, but is perhaps easier to work with Visitor pattern, which is essentially a strongly typed version of run-time type selection.

> Or shall I give up and resign?

Perhaps it is better to *redesign*. Converting the program to strongly typed algorithms may be advantageous.

Comment: since this question is tagged `qt`. I think that it is worth noting that Qt already has `QVariant`. . .

Comment: @Mike Thanks, That is what I'm looking for!